# How to implement user feed like in Twitter or Facebook on redis

Tags: database, redis, feed, timeline

I'm going to write simple news site on redis with supporting followers.
I can't imagine how can I organize users timeline like in twitter. I read about Retwis ( http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone ), but its feed creating method seems stupid. What if I want to remove entries? I'll should to remove all entry references from followers feeds. What if I already do not follow some users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to attack what you describe using a bit of imagination, here are some examples that address your questions:

> What if I want to remove entries?

One could mantain a set such as `post:$postid:users` for each post, holding all the userids that may have the post in their feeds; when the post is to be deleted one just has to extract all members from this set and iterate through the ids to remove it from each `uid:$userid:posts` set; speaking of which you would have to turn that last one into a set instead of a list like the original article suggests in order to be able to extract and remove individual items but that is trivial, the logic is pretty similar.

> What if I already do not follow some users?

When the feed is being generated for each individual user you have to necessarily iterate and read each `post:$postid` key, from which you have access to the author userid; so before showing the post you read this id and look it up in the `uid:$userid:following` set, if it's there we show the post, if it's not we delete it from `uid:$userid:posts` and don't show it.

In a nutshell, this is what you have to keep in mind in order to build this kind of logic in redis:

- You'll need many commands, but that's ok, Redis is supposed to be fast enough to handle it well.
- Data will repeat, but that is also ok; it may look insane for someone with a relational DBMS background to store a set of users for each post if each user already has a set with their posts, but this is the only way around building relationships in a non-relational data store like redis.
- Generally speaking think of sets and sorted sets when designing something relational in Redis.

With redis you get to do everything yourself, but once you get your head around it it's actually pretty powerful.

Comment: Thank you! If I unfollow user, I can remove all my posts from user's feed by `SDIFFSTORE uid:$userid:feed uid:$userid:feed uid:$myid:posts`

Comment: Yeah, that could also work. See, redis is quite flexible when you get the hang of it :)

Comment: @atomAltera Just a note, `SDIFFSTORE` has a `O(N)` time complexity, whereas removing the posts on the fly with the method I suggested should be `O(1)`, much faster for very large sets (think hundreds of thousands of posts)

Comment: Oh, I'm too wrong. `uid:$userid:feed` is a *list*.  I don't want posts of unfollowed user will be filtered in my feed because this reduce posts count on one page, of course this is tiny problem until I unfollow a lot of user. In this case the first page of feed can be empty or contains 2-3 posts, but second be full. @Mahn and what do you offer?

Comment: `uid:$userid:feed` can too be turned into a set, perhaps a sorted set using timestamps as the rank. If you were then to use `SDIFFSTORE`, you would just call it when an user is unfollowed, and then reload the feed using `ZRANGE uid:$userid:feed 0 10` or something similar, that should be okay.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16537/discussion-between-atomaltera-and-mahn)

Comment: True. The simplest way seems to be the one I suggest above of removing the posts as you go, but technically you could also copy the sorted set into a set, perform sdiffstore, and then iterate through the results to delete everything that doesn't match in the original sorted set, but this can get expensive with large sets.

Comment: OK. I hope redis developers add zdiff and zdiffstore in near future

Comment: I was gonna comment there's a thread on github about this here: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/446 but looks like you've seen it already :)